# How to get a tangent segment to a manipulated graph appear to be of constant length

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have made this program to plot a tangent line to a graph, but the thing I don't know how to fix is that the tangent line is at a fixed length, when I move the slider it expands and shortens. I want the line to be like a segment.

```
Tangent[f_, x_] := Module[{},
  Manipulate[
   Show[
    Plot [f'[p] (x - p) + f[p], {x, p - 1, p + 1},
     PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange},
     PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-70, 70}}],
    Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-70, 70}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {color}]
    ], {p, -10, 10, 
    0.2}, {color, {Purple -> "Purple", Blue -> "Blue"}}]
  ]

f[x_]:=x^2 Sin[x];

Tangent[f,x]
```

[image]

Comment: You're incrementing your $x$ value by $\pm 1$, and hence the length of the line segment will change.  Instead, scale the $x$ value so the full length is constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things to take into account:

1. The length of the tangent is proportional to $\sqrt{1+f'^2}$, and
2. The aspect ratio will need to be accounted for in order tor the
   segment to *appear* of constant length on screen. The aspect ratio
   relates to the actual coordinates through the bounds on the plots.

Here is one way to go about it:

```
a = 10; 
b = 70;
aspect = 2/3; (* aspect ratio is relevant to the segment length *)
l = 200; (* sets the length of the tangent *)

Tangent[f_, x_] := Module[{},
  Manipulate[
   m := l/Sqrt[b^2 + aspect^2 a^2 f'[p]^2];
   Show[
    Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-b, b}},
     AspectRatio -> aspect],
    Plot[f'[p] (x - p) + f[p], {x, p - m, p + m}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange}, PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-b, b}}]
    ],
   {p, -a, a, 0.2}]]

f[x_] := x^2 Sin[x];

Tangent[f, x]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I completely missed the aspect ratio part and was amazed why `1/Sqrt[1+f']` wasn't working lol