# Tangent line, slope and intercept at y=0 from data points

Tags: graphics, calculus-and-analysis, physics

If I have the following data:

```
https://pastebin.com/ti6pwnPP
```

Which plotted with `ListLinePlot[data]` looks like:

[image]

Questions:

1) How can I slide a tangent through different points?
2) How can I find the slope at those different points?
3) How can I find the intercept at y=0 from the different tangents (the ones tha apply)?.

I tried using a methodology similar to what was used here: [How to get a tangent segment to a manipulated graph appear to be of constant length](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140931/how-to-get-a-tangent-segment-to-a-manipulated-graph-appear-to-be-of-constant-len) but I am not sure how to do this with data.

EDIT:

This is the approach I have been trying to do so far:

```
tts1={};
peak[dataset_, {start_, end_}] := Module[{region, peak},
       region = Select[dataset, start <= #[[1]] <= end &];
       peak = Interpolation[region];
       peakfunction = AppendTo[tts1, peak];
       ];
```

Where after using `peak[data, {65, 80}]`, `peakfunction` gives me the InterpolatingFunction that fits the entire peak.

My problem is when I tried to use the similar approach used in [How to get a tangent segment to a manipulated graph appear to be of constant length](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140931/how-to-get-a-tangent-segment-to-a-manipulated-graph-appear-to-be-of-constant-len)

```
Tangent[f_, x_] := Module[{},
  Manipulate[
   Show[
    Plot [f'[p] (x - p) + f[p], {x, p - 1, p + 1},
     PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange},
     PlotRange -> {{50, 100}, {-0.1, 1.5}}],
    Plot[f[x], {x, 65, 80}, PlotRange -> {{50, 100}, {-0.1, 1.5}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {color}]
    ], {p, 65, 80, 
    0.2}, {color, {Purple -> "Purple"}]
  ]

f[x_]:=peakfunction[x];

Tangent[f,x]
```

I think in this approach (keep in mind I am a beginner in Mathematica) I cannot use `f[x_]:=peakfunction[x]` that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the tangent line to a function is:

$f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$

```
f = Interpolation[data];
Manipulate[
  Plot[{
      f[x],
      f[a] + f'[a] (x - a)
    },
    {x, 69, 79},
    PlotRange -> Full,
    Epilog -> {
      Point[{a, f[a]}],
      Text["Slope: " <> ToString[f'[a]], Scaled[{0.05, 0.95}], {-1, 1}],
      Text["Intercept: " <> ToString[f[a] - a f'[a]], Scaled[{0.05, 0.85}], {-1, 1}]
    }
  ],
 {{a, 70}, 69, 79}
 ]
```

[image]

`Interpolation` turns data into a function. It may not be as smooth as you had hoped, but I would need to know what kind of smoothing function you'd like to apply if I were to improve it any further.

Comment: MassDefect thank you so much! This is very good. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @John Sorry for my slow reply. The comment is gone now, but yes, it was supposed to be f not int. Thanks for catching that.